# BaseClass not change their value, if it change it in MainClass

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, python-class

So i have the problem: I put some numbers in variable on A class, create B class with another variable and equate them, but if I change A class variable they don't change in B class, output is still "123", maybe there is a option that can make B var change whenever change A var?

```python
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 123
Aa = A()

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.b = Aa.a
Bb = B(A)   

print(Bb.b)
c = int(input("Numbers: "))
Aa.a = c
print(Bb.b)
```

I tried a different def functions but they didn't work

Comment: Because that's not how Python works.  Integers cannot be changed.  When you create `Bb`, `Bb.a` it gets bound to the `123` object stored in `Aa.a`.  But when you do `Aa.a = c`, that assigns a brand new integer object to `Aa.a`, but it doesn't change anything in `Bb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want is a `@property` -- a method that acts like an attribute (every time you access the attribute, Python calls it as a method and returns the result).  This allows you to have an attribute that automatically references some other value or computes its own dynamic value rather than being a normal variable.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 123

class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._a.a


Aa = A()
Bb = B(Aa)
print(Bb.b) # 123
Aa.a = 42
print(Bb.b) # 42
```

Note that each `B` object **has a** reference to an `A` object, but it is not necessary (or desirable) for `B` to itself **be** a subclass of `A`.  You generally want to use composition (**has a**) *or* inheritance (**is a**), not both at once.  In this case, composition makes more sense.

Comment: Your answer does do what he asked about, but I think it's important to point out that this is not a common pattern, and suggests incorrect thinking about the problem.  Users, in particular, are going to be very surprised when `Bb.b` changes without having made any changes to `Bb`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is exactly the same as this:

```
i = 7
j = i
i = 9
print(j)
```

Would you expect `j` to print 9?  It won't because `j` is still bound to the `7` object.